# Can beast be used with C++20's co_await keyword?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

C++20 introduced [language support for coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines). My understanding is that that this consists of syntactic sugar, such as `co_await` and `co_return`, to which semantic meaning is attached via special "hooks".

The language support allows for idiomatic expression of asynchronous logic; in effect, allowing for code that reads sequentially, even where it uses callback mechanisms under the hood.

Does Boost.Beast have any support for C++20 coroutines, and if so, how can the two be used together? In particular, is it possible to read and write messages asynchronously over an unencrypted or SSL-encrypted websocket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Richard just said. Here's the `websocket_client_coro_ssl.cpp` example reworked:

```
//
// Copyright (c) 2016-2019 Vinnie Falco (vinnie dot falco at gmail dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// Official repository: https://github.com/boostorg/beast
//

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Example: WebSocket SSL client, c++20 coroutines
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "/home/sehe/custom/superboost/libs/beast/example/common/root_certificates.hpp"

#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/as_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>

#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
net::awaitable<void>
do_session(
    std::string host,
    std::string const& port,
    std::string const& text,
    ssl::context& ctx)
{
    using net::use_awaitable;
    using net::experimental::as_tuple;

    auto ex = co_await net::this_coro::executor;
    // These objects perform our I/O
    tcp::resolver resolver(ex);
    websocket::stream<
        beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws(ex, ctx);

    try
    {
        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = co_await resolver.async_resolve(
            host, port, use_awaitable);

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_after(
            std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        auto ep = co_await beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).async_connect(
            results, use_awaitable);

        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake
        // successfully)
        if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(
               ws.next_layer().native_handle(), host.c_str()))
        {
            throw beast::system_error(
                static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()),
                net::error::get_ssl_category());
        }

        // Update the host string. This will provide the value of the
        // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
        // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_after(
            std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(
                    http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-client-coro");
            }));

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        co_await ws.next_layer().async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client, use_awaitable);

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
            beast::role_type::client));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        co_await ws.async_handshake(host, "/", use_awaitable);

        // Send the message
        co_await ws.async_write(
            net::buffer(std::string(text)), use_awaitable);

        // This buffer will hold the incoming message
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Read a message into our buffer
        auto [ec, bytes] =
            co_await ws.async_read(buffer, as_tuple(use_awaitable));

        if(ec)
        {
            // eof is to be expected for some services
            if(ec != net::error::eof)
                throw beast::system_error(ec);
        } else
        {
            // The make_printable() function helps print a
            // ConstBufferSequence
            std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data())
                      << std::endl;

            // Close the WebSocket connection
            co_await ws.async_close(
                websocket::close_code::normal, use_awaitable);
        }

    } catch(beast::system_error const& se)
    {
        //std::cerr << "Handled: " << se.code().message() << "\n";
        throw; // handled at the spawn site instead
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "Usage: websocket-client-coro-ssl <host> <port> <text>\n" <<
            "Example:\n" <<
            "    websocket-client-coro-ssl echo.websocket.org 443 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const text = argv[3];

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

    // This holds the root certificate used for verification
    load_root_certificates(ctx);

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    net::co_spawn(
        ioc.get_executor(),
        do_session(host, port, text, ctx),
        [&](std::exception_ptr e)
        {
            try
            {
                std::rethrow_exception(e);
            } catch(std::exception const& e)
            {
                std::cerr << "Err: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        });

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the socket is closed.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should pass asio::use_awaitable as the completion token type, then co_await the value returned by the asynchronous initiation function.

If you want an error code rather than exception on failure, pass asio::experimental::as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable) as the completion token.